# Did Samuel actually see David in person when he consecrated him in 1 Samuel 16:5?

Tags: 1-samuel

> 1 Samuel 16:5
> Samuel replied, "Yes, in peace; I have come to sacrifice to the LORD. Consecrate yourselves and come to the sacrifice with me." Then **he consecrated Jesse and his sons** and invited them to the sacrifice.

Hadn't Samuel seen David at this point?

> 11 So he asked Jesse, “Are these all the sons you have?”
> “There is still the youngest,” Jesse answered. “He is tending the sheep.”
> Samuel said, “Send for him; we will not sit down until he arrives.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The story as recorded in 1 Sam 16 is quite clear.  When the prophet Samuel arrived at Jesse's home, he met Jesse and all but the youngest of the sons, David who was out in the fields minding the sheep.

Thus, as the narrative is presented, David was absent when the "consecration" was done in V5.  However, note the subtle distinction made.  Let me quote 1 Sam 16:4, 5 -

> **4** So Samuel did what the LORD had said and went to Bethlehem. When the elders of the town met him, they trembled and asked, “Do you come
> in peace?”  **5** “In peace,” he replied. “I have come to sacrifice to
> the LORD. Consecrate yourselves and come with me to the sacrifice.”
> Then he consecrated Jesse and his sons and invited them to the
> sacrifice.

There were two groups of people present for this little local feast:

1. The elders and officials of Bethlehem
2. Jesse's family excluding David

Note that Samuel sanctified Jesse's family but everyone else sanctified themselves.  However, David was not present for either.

Ultimately, David was consecrated after he was called (V11, 12) and he was anointed, set apart, for the sacred office of King of Israel (V13).